# Transitioning to HTML 'subcategory' page without explicitly opening another HTML file (Mobile Response)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

The following image shows what I am trying to achieve. 
A HTML page transitioning the view to another page, without actually having to redirect to another HTML file. 
The website has a nice sliding animation when you click on a category, like on mobile when entering certain sections of the 'app'.

Website: https://app.ignition.fun/

I am intermediate at web development, so please dumb it down when trying to explain; I'd assume this stuff is quite complex :P

Thanks.

Comment: This is the image with the transition. Or you can just use the website i posted above. https://imgur.com/a/EpE7Q1m

Comment: What you're trying to build is a "single page app". These usually involve using a JavaScript web framework such as Reach, Angular, or Vue.

Comment: My personal website (link in my profile) attempts to achieve a single-page-app without a JS framework. It's all one HTML file, so just take a look at the source to see how it works.